# Fedora 27 - VirtualBox repo empty?

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

I'm trying to install VirtualBox 5.2 onto my Fedora 27 dektop box. As per [Oracle's official guide](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), I added the Fedora repo file, however dnf cannot find the VirtualBox package and claims the repo contains zero packages:

```
# dnf install VirtualBox-5.2
Last metadata expiration check: 1:03:19 ago on Do 01 Mär 2018 11:27:35 CET.
No match for argument: VirtualBox-5.2
Error: Unable to find a match

# dnf repolist --all
Last metadata expiration check: 0:57:04 ago on Do 01 Mär 2018 11:27:35 CET.
repo id                                                                     repo name                                                                                status
*fedora                                                                     Fedora 27 - x86_64                                                                       enabled: 54.801
fedora-debuginfo                                                            Fedora 27 - x86_64 - Debug                                                               disabled
fedora-source                                                               Fedora 27 - Source                                                                       disabled
[...]
virtualbox                                                                  Fedora 27 - x86_64 - VirtualBox                                                          enabled:      0
```

I can clearly see packages when I open the repo URL in a browser. What am I missing?
**edit**: I couldn't figure out what was wrong, downloaded the appropriate RPM file from virtualbox.org and installed that. It's only the second best solution, but got me a working VirtualBox installation.

Comment: What do you get with `dnf --repo=virtualbox list available`?

Comment: @mattdm Nothing, effectively, it just tells me the last metadata check date and then returns.

Comment: 1.5 years and 3 major releases later, I finally found the issue: For some reason, I had added an "exclude=VirtualBox*" to my /etc/dnf/dnf.conf . Removed that, and installation worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the repo:

```
sudo dnf install VirtualBox
```

more infos:

To search for the valide package name:

```
sudo dnf search virtualbox
```

It will return something like:

```
VirtualBox.x86_64 : A general-purpose full virtualizer for PC hardware
```

You don't need to add the architecture when you install it(.x86_64).